# Groovy: Many to one XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, groovy

Is it possible to transform an array on input Xmls into single Xml by XSLT transformation?
Currently I am using following to code which is pretty straightforward.

> One Xml -> One XSLT -> One output Xml

**Code**

```
def w = new StringWriter()
TransformerFactory.newInstance()
                  .newTransformer( new StreamSource( new StringReader( xslt ) ) )
                  .transform( new StreamSource( new StringReader( xmlAsString ) ),
                              new StreamResult( w ) )
```

Comment: Assuming they are files, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210134/how-to-merge-multiple-xml-files-using-xsl

Comment: @tim_yates Thanks Tim. I saw this post before. In my case input xmls are not files.

Comment: Then no, I don't believe you can

Answer (score 0):

The concept is that you have one input file, one transformation file and one output file. I think you cannot do a XSLT transformation with more than one input file (you could merge them before but this is not very elegant).

However you can access as many documents in your XSLT Stylesheet as you want by using the document function. I would do it like that: Define an input file that includes all the documents you want to access e.g.

```
<files>
   <file>
     <path>File1.xml</path>
   </file>

   <file>
     <path>File2.xml</path>
   </file>
</files>
```

Take this file as an input file and use the document function to access them:

```
<xsl:template match = "file">
    <xsl:copy-of select="document(./path)/..."/>
</xsl:template>
```

With the document function, you can access all input files and apply transformations to the nodes specified there. So you can handle an arbitrary number of input files.