# For Each File in Folder, Include XML

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, xslt

I have a lengthy XML like so:

MainXML.xml:

```
<OpenTag>
    <SubTag>Value 1</SubTag>
    <SubTag>Value 2</SubTag>
    <SubTag>Value 3</SubTag>
    <SubTag>Value 4</SubTag>
</OpenTag>
```

Except that `SubTag` is a more complex repeated structure with a lot of data.  Couldn't I somehow do this instead?:

SubXML1.xml:

```
<SubTag>Value 1</SubTag>
```

SubXML2.xml:

```
<SubTag>Value 2</SubTag>
```

SubXML3.xml:

```
<SubTag>Value 3</SubTag>
```

SubXML4.xml:

```
<SubTag>Value 4</SubTag>
```

MainXML.xml:

```
<OpenTag>
    ... For Each XML File in the Sub-XML Folder, stick it here.
</OpenTag>
```

I realize I can do this with basic File and String functions, but wanted to know if there was a native way with XSL/XML to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are OK with LINQ to XML, here is a working code:

```
public static XDocument AggregateMultipleXmlFilesIntoASingleOne(string parentFolderPath, string fileNamePrefix)
{
    return new XDocument(
        new XElement("OpenTag", 
            Directory.GetFiles(parentFolderPath)
                .Where(file => Path.GetFileName(file).StartsWith(fileNamePrefix))
                .Select(XDocument.Load)
                .Select(doc => new XElement(doc.Root))
                .ToArray()));
}
```

Comment: Wowza.  Assuming that works, which it seems like it would, that's pretty slick.  And yes, I'm a big LINQ user.  I do hope for a non-code example, something in XSLT or something.  So I wont choose an answer until hopefully something along that line shows up.  But definitely an up-vote for the slick-ness.

Comment: Last time I used XSLT, was lo-o-ong ago, on .Net 2.0. And then Microsoft decided to not support XSLT 2.0... But [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210134/how-to-merge-multiple-xml-files-using-xsl) could be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks!  I actually didn't want to "lead" answers with that.  I was really hoping for something like that, but inside a For-Each loop to get file-names from a folder.  I don't think this exactly thing is possible, but hopefully something like that is possible.

Comment: Actually, you can add an [extension object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addextensionobject.aspx) to your XSLT in order to get the files list.

Comment: I believe this is the closest that I'll get to an answer, and it is indeed pretty close.  I understand that as of now, it's not possible to do what I want natively in XML/XSLT.  Extension is a good idea, but LINQ to XML is probably the route I'll go.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are after, but it seems to work OK. It relies on XSLT 2.0, hopefulyl you can use that. You also need to have a folder ready for the SubXML files:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>    

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//SubTag">
        <xsl:result-document href="folder/SubXML{position()}.xml" method="xml">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That solution is pretty good.  The thing is, it relies on me editing the main file and, at minimum, placing the same number of SubTag tags as there are files.  If I have to edit the main file each time I create a new sub file, I might as well just add a new file name.