# Is there a way to combine parts of several XML docs into one?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have several XML documents all containing metadata information about the same item. The XML documents are identical EXCEPT for one element. Is there a way, using XSLT, to transform these multiple docs into one output XML that contains the information from all?
In my separate docs, I have metadata that looks like this:

```
<pbcorePart>
  <pbcoreIdentifier source="something" 
                    annotation="Object Identifier"
    >filename_t10</pbcoreIdentifier>
  <!-- a bunch of other stuff about this item -->
</pbcorePart>
```

But what I ultimately need is one XML file that combines all of the parts into one document using a relation tag, so it looks like this:

```
  <pbcoreRelation>
    <pbcoreRelationType>has part</pbcoreRelationType>
    <pbcoreRelationIdentifier>filename_t01</pbcoreRelationIdentifier>
  </pbcoreRelation>
  <pbcoreRelation>
    <pbcoreRelationType>has part</pbcoreRelationType>
    <pbcoreRelationIdentifier>filename_t02</pbcoreRelationIdentifier>
  </pbcoreRelation>
  <pbcoreRelation>
    <pbcoreRelationType>has part</pbcoreRelationType>
```

etc.

Is there a way to do this with an XSLT transformation?

I'm still new at creating XSLT, and I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xpath-default-namespace="http://www.pbcore.org/PBCore/PBCoreNamespace.html">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>



<xsl:template match="@* | node()">

    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="test">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document('csmha_000110_t03.xml')/pbcoreDescriptionDocument/pbcorePart"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document('csmha_000110_t04.xml')/pbcoreDescriptionDocument/pbcorePart"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9210206/2516718 ?

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes, there are many ways".  What have you tried so far?  If you show what you've managed to do, people here can help you further; if you don't show what you've tried, or if you haven't actually tried anything, then all we can do is say yes, what you want to do is in fact possible.

Comment: I've tried merging multiple XML files into one, but that doesn't accomplish what I need, since I only need parts of each XML, not the entire content.

Comment: I've tried this:

Comment: I added the code that I have tried in an XSLT.