# XSLT Mapping - combining multiple related XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to explore and learn XSLT mapping with a pretty basic requirement though I am not sure on how to proceed.

Basically I have multiple payloads.

Payload 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
  <header>
    <quoteType>YQT</quoteType>
    <salesOrg>5010</salesOrg>
    <distributionChannel>00</distributionChannel>
    <division>00</division>
    <deliveryDateHeader>2022-09-29T00:00Z</deliveryDateHeader>
    <shippingCondition>01</shippingCondition>
  </header>
  <partner>
    <partnerNumber>100193</partnerNumber>
    <partnerFunction>SP</partnerFunction>
  </partner>
  <partner>
    <partnerNumber>100193</partnerNumber>
    <partnerFunction>WE</partnerFunction>
  </partner>
  <partner>
    <partnerNumber>100193</partnerNumber>
    <partnerFunction>RE</partnerFunction>
  </partner>
  <materialsAvailibility>
    <itemNumber>110</itemNumber>
    <materialNumber>188521</materialNumber>
  </materialsAvailibility>
</root>
```

Payload 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
  <header>
    <quoteType>YQT</quoteType>
    <salesOrg>5010</salesOrg>
    <distributionChannel>00</distributionChannel>
    <division>00</division>
    <deliveryDateHeader>2022-09-29T00:00Z</deliveryDateHeader>
    <shippingCondition>01</shippingCondition>
  </header>
  <partner>
    <partnerNumber>100193</partnerNumber>
    <partnerFunction>SP</partnerFunction>
  </partner>
  <partner>
    <partnerNumber>100193</partnerNumber>
    <partnerFunction>WE</partnerFunction>
  </partner>
  <partner>
    <partnerNumber>100193</partnerNumber>
    <partnerFunction>RE</partnerFunction>
  </partner>
  <materialsAvailibility>
    <itemNumber>10</itemNumber>
    <materialNumber>115517</materialNumber>
  </materialsAvailibility>
</root>
```

Expected Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
  <header>
    <quoteType>YQT</quoteType>
    <salesOrg>5010</salesOrg>
    <distributionChannel>00</distributionChannel>
    <division>00</division>
    <deliveryDateHeader>2022-09-29T00:00Z</deliveryDateHeader>
    <shippingCondition>01</shippingCondition>
  </header>
  <partner>
    <partnerNumber>100193</partnerNumber>
    <partnerFunction>SP</partnerFunction>
  </partner>
  <partner>
    <partnerNumber>100193</partnerNumber>
    <partnerFunction>WE</partnerFunction>
  </partner>
  <partner>
    <partnerNumber>100193</partnerNumber>
    <partnerFunction>RE</partnerFunction>
  </partner>
 <materialsAvailibility>
    <itemNumber>110</itemNumber>
    <materialNumber>188521</materialNumber>
  </materialsAvailibility>
  <materialsAvailibility>
    <itemNumber>10</itemNumber>
    <materialNumber>115517</materialNumber>
  </materialsAvailibility>
</root>
```

The header and partner nodes are always identical and I just need to collate the materialAvailibility together. Can someone help provide a working XSLT mapping for this and I will try to study what does the specific lines do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "payloads" you show are not well-formed XML documents (lack a single root element) and cannot be used as the input to XSLT.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge multiple xml files using xsl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210134/how-to-merge-multiple-xml-files-using-xsl)

Comment: P.S. In all your questions regarding XSLT, please state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - hi Michael, originally the XMLs have root element but I purposely removed it as I didn't know that it is needed in doing XSLT mapping.

Also the XSLT version that we use is 3.0 Saxon-EE.

Comment: It is needed in order to have a [mcve]. It is also not clear what exactly you mean by "combining". Does it involve checking for and removing duplicates? If so, at what level?

Comment: Hi Michael, I have corrected already my original post but to answer your question there are no checks needed as we don't expect any duplicates. The header and partner nodes are identical between my first XML and second XML. But for the target output, I just need the same header and partner nodes but this time also including the 2 different materialAvailibility nodes in one XML file. Thanks

Comment: If so, this is a trivial problem. Use one of the documents as the input, match on the root element and copy all its children. Then copy the `materialsAvailibility` elements from the other document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following powershell script. Code works without the root node.

```
using assembly System.Collections
using assembly System.Xml
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$inputFilename1 = "C:\temp\test.xml"
$inputFilename2 = "C:\temp\test1.xml"
$outputFilename = "C:\temp\test2.xml"


$rSettings = New-Object System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings
$rSettings.ConformanceLevel = [System.Xml.ConformanceLevel]::Fragment

$reader1 = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create($inputFilename1,$rSettings)
$nodes1 = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]
while($reader1.EOF -eq $False)
{
   if($reader1.IsStartElement() -eq $False) {$reader2.MoveToContent()}

   $nodes1.Add([System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::ReadFrom($reader1));
}

$reader2 = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create($inputFilename2,$rSettings)
$nodes2 = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]
while($reader2.EOF -eq $False)
{
   if($reader2.IsStartElement() -eq $False) {$reader2.MoveToContent()}

   $nodes2.Add([System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::ReadFrom($reader2));
}

$materialsAvailibility2 = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where($nodes2, [Func[object,bool]]{ param($x) $x.Name.LocalName -eq "materialsAvailibility"})
$materialsAvailibility2 = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::First($materialsAvailibility2)
$materialsAvailibility2 = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]$materialsAvailibility2
#Write-Host $materialsAvailibility2
$nodes1.Add($materialsAvailibility2)

$sWriter = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($outputFilename)
$sWriter.WriteLine("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" ?>");

$wSettings = New-Object System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
$wSettings.ConformanceLevel = [System.Xml.ConformanceLevel]::Fragment
$wSettings.Indent = $True;

$xWriter = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create($sWriter,$wSettings);
foreach ($node1 in $nodes1)
{
#Write-Host $node1
   $node1.WriteTo($xWriter);     
#Write-Host "end"
}
            
$xWriter.Flush();
$xWriter.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is probably

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="*, doc('payload2.xml')//materialsAvailability"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```